# How to find zeros of tensorflow function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm starting to learn Tensorflow and set as an exercise for myself to find the zeros of a function. The approach I took was as follows:

```
x = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=True)  # Independent variable
y = 2*tf.pow(x,2) - 6*x + 4           # Function for which to find 0's
loss = tf.pow(y,2)                    # Function with minima at 0 of y(x)
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss) # Optimizer

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1000): # Minimizing loop
        print sess.run([x,y, loss])
        sess.run(opt)
```

I expected that finding the minima of loss (i.e. y^2) would give me the the zeros of y.  However, when I tried the above code, I got these results:

```
[0.0, 4.0, 16.0]
[4.8, 21.280005, 452.83856]
[-51.37921, 5591.9224, 31269596.0]
[236505.78, 111868550000.0, 1.2514572e+22]
[-2.1165915e+16, 8.959919e+32, inf]
[inf, nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan]
```

What did I do wrong? I was expecting to "discover" that y had a zero at x=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning rate is too large. Smaller learning rate like 0.01 produces the result below:

```
[0.0, 4.0, 16.0]
[0.48, 1.5808, 2.4989288]
[0.6089933, 1.087786, 1.1832783]
[0.68653125, 0.82346296, 0.6780912]
[0.7401202, 0.65483475, 0.42880854]
[0.77992785, 0.5370076, 0.28837714]
[0.8108626, 0.44982052, 0.2023385]
[0.83566165, 0.3826909, 0.14645232]
[0.85600054, 0.3294704, 0.10855074]
[0.8729749, 0.28632116, 0.08197981]
[0.8873373, 0.25071096, 0.06285599]
[0.8996254, 0.2208991, 0.048796415]
[0.9102352, 0.19564486, 0.03827691]
[0.91946596, 0.17403984, 0.030289866]
[0.9275488, 0.15540075, 0.024149394]
[0.93466556, 0.13920641, 0.019378424]     
[0.9409614, 0.12504816, 0.015637042]
[0.94655395, 0.112605095, 0.0126799075]
[0.95153964, 0.101617336, 0.010326083]
[0.9559983, 0.09187603, 0.008441205]
```

This will converge to 1.

UPDATE: Description of divergent phenomenon of the original code.

As you can see, x coordinates of your results are interpreted as the oscillation around the optimal solution x = 1. More distant x ordinate is, a larger gradient is produced. Finally, loss exceeds the largest value `tf.float32` can express, resulting in `inf`.